# Nightwatch : Unable to create new service : ChromeDriverService

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I am trying to automate a simple test case using Nightwatch framework of validating a login. I have followed the steps mentioned on : https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/browser-automation-with-nightwatch-and-selenium/

The problem arises when I execute the command node nightwatch tests/bing_test.js in node.js command prompt which results in a error message.

Below is my nightwatch.json configs :

```
{
    "src_folders": ["tests"],
    "output_folder": "reports",
    "custom_commands_path": "",
    "custom_assertions_path": "",
    "page_objects_path": "",
    "globals_path": "",

    "selenium": {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": "./lib/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar",
        "log_path": "./reports",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 4445,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./lib/drivers/chromedriver.exe",
            "webdriver.gecko.driver": "./lib/drivers/geckodriver.exe",
            "webdriver.edge.driver": "./lib/drivers/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"
        }
    },

    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "launch_url": "http://localhost",
            "selenium_port": 4445,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "silent": true,
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": true,
                "path": "./reports/screenshots"
            },
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "marionette": true,
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true
            }
        },
        "chrome": {
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome" 
            }
        },

        "firefox": {
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "firefox" 
            }
        },

        "edge": {
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message :

```
[Bing Test] Test Suite
======================
   Response 500 POST /wd/hub/session (363ms)
   { value:
      { error:
         [ "Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'",
           "System info: host: 'PDC2LAP-7173253', ip: '192.168.43.196', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'",
           'Driver info: driver.version: unknown' ],
        message: 'Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService' },
     status: 33 }
   An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService"
       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
_________________________________________________

TEST FAILURE: 1 error during execution 0 tests failed, 0 passed. 2.886s

 × bing_test

  An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService"
       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)

   SKIPPED:
   - Bing search test
```

I have tried to debug the issue by going through the comments on GIT forum by setting "webdriver.chrome.driver": "" and "start_process": false, but none of the two worked.

ChromeDriver Version - v72
Selenium Standalone Jar - 3.8.1

Please feel free to guide me to any existing answer/documentation that persists for this issue.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the version of chromedriver that you are using is the appropriate one for the version of theChrome browser you want to test with?